# Magento Product Addtocart go to Checkout Page by skipping Cart Page gives suggested Tutorial or any information

Tags: checkout, overrides, controllers

Please suggest a tutorial or any example on how to change exciting controller using local folder and local code. I want change in cart controller. I do when **click** on **Add To Cart** then it redirects to **checkout page**. Please Tell What I change and How to change. I am making cart controller override. It's working, but what can change in this controller to **direct** redirect to check out page.

Comment: "How to change **exciting** controller" what exactly are you trying to say here?

Comment: Means I am override cart controller. I am creating a module for it. And it's working. But I can do when click on Add to cart, then its a direct redirect to check out page.

Comment: and...? if you want an Ajax add-to-cart then you'll either have to code it yourself, or look for a module on the Internet.

Comment: No, I am just a simple redirect to check out page. I just learn how to change in exciting Controller using override.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't udnerstand what you want. I suggest you change transltator if you're using one.

Comment: If You have any tutorial  or any examples site plaese suggest me. On site complete instruction for beginning development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already managed to overload the controller, you can achieve a redirect to the checkout page like that:

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class My_Module_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addAction()
    {
        $returnUrl = Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage');
        $this->getRequest()->setParam('return_url', $returnUrl);
        parent::addAction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no exciting controller, I think your using some custom tutorial for over riding.
In order to over ride cart controller:

Create:

> /app/code/local/Namespace/Cart/etc/config.xml

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Namespace_Cart before=”Mage_Checkout”>Namespace_Cart_Checkout</Namespace_Cart>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

> /app/code/local/Namespace/Cart/controllers/Checkout/CartController.php

```
require_once ‘Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class Namespace_Cart_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo ‘File overriden';
        exit;
    }
    public function addAction()
    {
        die('do you action'); 
    }
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11349530/magento-override-controller) has a lot of discussion on this:

Comment: It's Also a good example for me. Thank you Very Much